# Creating a nested pack from all its types read from left to right

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

My ultimate goal is, given all the types read from left to right, to create a nested pack of any complexity by specifying where all the inner packs begin and their corresponding lengths (i.e. where they end).  This is essentially the reverse of flattening a nested pack.

I've already written `create_nested_pack`, which creates a nested pack where each pack can only have one nested pack, though there can be any number of nestings.  It can be used as follows:

```
template <typename...> struct P;
template <typename...> struct Q;
template <typename...> struct R;
template <std::size_t...> struct Z;
template <template <typename...> class...> struct A;

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_nested_pack<Z<2,1,0>, Z<3,2,2>, A<P>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>::type,
        P<int, long, P<bool, P<P<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float, double>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_nested_pack<Z<2,1,0>, Z<3,2,2>, A<P,Q,R>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>::type,
        P<int, long, Q<bool, R<R<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float, double>
    >::value);
}
```

The first Z-pack specifies the positions (0-based) of each inner pack in their corresponding outer packs, and the second Z-pack indicates their corresponding lengths.

I've considered starting from scratch to tackle the more general construction where each pack can have any number of "sibling packs" (my above construction has no sibling packs), but my gut tells me that I can carry that out by using my `create_nested_pack` repeatedly somehow.  But I'm stuck on how to do that.  Can someone think of a way?  Or is my only choice to start all over and think of a completely new implementation?

Here is my implementation (and test) of `create_nested_pack`, which I renamed to `create_simple_nested_pack`, along with `simple_nested_pack_traits`, which illustrates flattening and then restoring a nested pack:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
    template <typename T> struct is_pack : std::false_type { };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
    struct is_pack<P<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

    template <typename... Packs> struct merge;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q, typename... Us>
    struct merge<P<Ts...>, Q<Us...>> {
        using type = P<Ts..., Us...>;   
    };

    template <typename First, typename... Rest>
    struct merge<First, Rest...> : merge<First, typename merge<Rest...>::type> { };

    template <typename Pack> struct pack_size;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
    struct pack_size<P<Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> { };

    template <template <auto...> class Z, auto... Is>
    struct pack_size<Z<Is...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)> { };

    template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, T... Is>
    struct pack_size<Z<T, Is...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)> { };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto make_head (P<Ts...>&&, std::index_sequence<Is...>&&) -> P<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;

    template <std::size_t Size, typename Pack>
    struct head {  // Gives the first Size types in Pack.
        using type = decltype(make_head(std::declval<Pack>(), std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}));   
    };

    template <std::size_t Shift, template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto make_middle_section (P<Ts...>&&, std::index_sequence<Is...>&&) -> P<std::tuple_element_t<Is + Shift, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;

    template <std::size_t Skip, std::size_t Size, typename Pack>
    struct middle_section {  // Gives all the Size types in Pack after the first Skip types.
        using type = decltype(make_middle_section<Skip>(std::declval<Pack>(), std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}));   
    };

    template <std::size_t Skip, typename Pack>  // Gives all the types of Pack except for the first Skip types.
    struct exclude_head : middle_section<Skip, pack_size<Pack>::value - Skip, Pack> { };

    template <typename Pack> struct sum;

    template <template <auto...> class Z, auto... Is>
    struct sum<Z<Is...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, (0 + ... + Is)> { };

    template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class...> struct change_template;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q>
    struct change_template<P<Ts...>, Q> {
        using type = Q<Ts...>;  
    };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q, template <typename...> class R, template <typename...> class... Rest>
    struct change_template<P<Ts...>, Q, R, Rest...> {
        using type = R<Ts...>;  // For create_nested_pack_h, we want to switch to the second template if there is a second template.
    };

    template <typename Pack, typename T> struct append;
    template <typename Pack, auto Value> struct append_to_sequence;
    template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P> struct append_template;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename T>
    struct append<P<Ts...>, T> {
        using type = P<Ts..., T>;   
    };


    template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, auto... Is, auto Value>
    struct append_to_sequence<Z<T, Is...>, Value> {
        using type = Z<T, Is..., Value>;    
    };

    template <template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class... Ps, template <typename...> class P>
    struct append_template<A<Ps...>, P> {
        using type = A<Ps..., P>;
    };

    struct generic {
        template <std::size_t... Is> struct K;
        template <template <typename...> class...> struct L;

        template <std::size_t... Is>
        using Z = K<Is...>;

        template <template <typename...> class... Ps>
        using A = L<Ps...>;
    };
}

template <std::size_t Length, typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename Types> struct create_simple_nested_pack_h;

// The innermost pack is reached and completed immediately.  Only one template type can be in the A-pack at this point.
template <std::size_t Length, template <std::size_t...> class Z, template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class P, typename Types>
struct create_simple_nested_pack_h<Length, Z<>, Z<>, A<P>, Types> {
    static constexpr std::size_t num_types = Length;
    using type = typename detail::change_template<typename detail::head<Length, Types>::type, P>::type;
};

// An inner pack is reached and completed using recursion.
template <std::size_t Length, template <std::size_t...> class Z, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t J, std::size_t... Js, template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class... Ps, typename Types>
struct create_simple_nested_pack_h<Length, Z<I, Is...>, Z<J, Js...>, A<P, Ps...>, Types> {
    using head_of_pack = typename detail::head<I, Types>::type;  // The wrapping template used is P.
    using templates_left = std::conditional_t<sizeof...(Ps) == 0, A<P>, A<Ps...>>;  // If sizeof...(Ps) == 0, then we use P as the wrapping template for all remaining inner packs.
    using exclude_head_of_pack = typename detail::change_template<typename detail::exclude_head<I, Types>::type, P, Ps...>::type;  // Skip the first I types to create the first inner pack of the overall pack.  The wrapping template is P if sizeof...(Ps) == 0, else it is the first template from Ps...
    using nested = create_simple_nested_pack_h<J, Z<Is...>, Z<Js...>, templates_left, exclude_head_of_pack>;
    using inner_pack = typename nested::type;
    using tail_of_pack = typename detail::middle_section<nested::num_types, Length - 1 - I, exclude_head_of_pack>::type;
    static constexpr std::size_t num_types = nested::num_types + Length - 1;
    using type = typename detail::merge<head_of_pack, P<inner_pack>, tail_of_pack>::type;
};

// create_simple_nested_pack and its twin class unflatten_pack.
template <typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename... Ts> struct create_simple_nested_pack;

template <typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class... Ps, typename... Ts>
struct create_simple_nested_pack<StartingPositions, PackLengths, A<P, Ps...>, Ts...> : create_simple_nested_pack_h<sizeof...(Ts) - (detail::sum<PackLengths>::value - detail::pack_size<PackLengths>::value), StartingPositions, PackLengths, A<P, Ps...>, P<Ts...>> { };

template <typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename Types> struct unflatten_pack;

template <typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct unflatten_pack<StartingPositions, PackLengths, Templates, P<Ts...>> : create_simple_nested_pack<StartingPositions, PackLengths, Templates, Ts...> { };

template <std::size_t... Is, std::size_t... Js, typename Templates, template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct unflatten_pack<std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...>, Templates, P<Ts...>> : create_simple_nested_pack<detail::generic::Z<Is...>, detail::generic::Z<Js...>, Templates, Ts...> { };

// nested_pack_traits
template <typename Pack> struct simple_nested_pack_traits : std::false_type { };
template <std::size_t Count, typename Pack, typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename Types, typename OuterpackTypes, typename = void> struct simple_nested_pack_traits_h;

// The end of the innermost pack is reached.
template <std::size_t Count, template <typename...> class P, typename Last, typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename Types, typename OuterPackTypes>
struct simple_nested_pack_traits_h<Count, P<Last>, StartingPositions, PackLengths, Templates, Types, OuterPackTypes, std::enable_if_t<!detail::is_pack<Last>::value>> : std::true_type {  // 'std::enable_if_t<!detail::is_pack<Last>::value>' is needed to avoid ambiguity with the specialization below when Rest... is empty.
    using starting_positions = StartingPositions;
    using pack_lengths = PackLengths;  // Don't append Count+1 to this, as the length of this innermost pack has already been appended previously.
    using templates = Templates;
    using types = typename detail::merge<Types, std::tuple<Last>, OuterPackTypes>::type;
    static constexpr std::size_t depth = detail::pack_size<StartingPositions>::value;
};

// An inner pack is reached.
template <std::size_t Count, template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class Q, typename... Ts, typename... Rest, typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename Types, typename OuterPackTypes>
struct simple_nested_pack_traits_h<Count, P<Q<Ts...>, Rest...>, StartingPositions, PackLengths, Templates, Types, OuterPackTypes> :
    simple_nested_pack_traits_h<0, Q<Ts...>, typename detail::append_to_sequence<StartingPositions, Count>::type, typename detail::append_to_sequence<PackLengths, sizeof...(Ts)>::type,
    typename detail::append_template<Templates, Q>::type, Types, typename detail::merge<std::tuple<Rest...>, OuterPackTypes>::type> { };

// Counting and appending the types before reaching the inner pack (if any).
template <std::size_t Count, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename StartingPositions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename Types, typename OuterPackTypes>
struct simple_nested_pack_traits_h<Count, P<First, Rest...>, StartingPositions, PackLengths, Templates, Types, OuterPackTypes, std::enable_if_t<!detail::is_pack<First>::value>> :
    simple_nested_pack_traits_h<Count + 1, P<Rest...>, StartingPositions, PackLengths, Templates, typename detail::append<Types, First>::type, OuterPackTypes> { };

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct simple_nested_pack_traits<P<Ts...>> : simple_nested_pack_traits_h<0, P<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<>, std::index_sequence<>, detail::generic::A<P>, P<>, P<>> { };

template <typename Pack>
struct flatten_pack {
    using type = typename simple_nested_pack_traits<Pack>::types;   // Note that this flattening only works for nested packs where no inner pack has a sibling inner pack.  This is good enough for testing here, but flatten_pack.cpp would be used in the general case.
};

// Test
template <typename...> struct P;
template <typename...> struct Q;
template <typename...> struct R;
template <std::size_t...> struct Z;
template <template <typename...> class...> struct A;

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_simple_nested_pack<Z<2>, Z<3>, A<P>, int, long, bool, int, bool, char, int>::type,
        P<int, long, P<bool, int, bool>, char, int>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_simple_nested_pack<Z<2>, Z<3>, A<P,Q>, int, long, bool, int, bool, char, int>::type,
        P<int, long, Q<bool, int, bool>, char, int>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_simple_nested_pack<Z<2,1>, Z<3,2>, A<P>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, float, double>::type,
        P<int, long, P<bool, P<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_simple_nested_pack<Z<2,1>, Z<3,2>, A<P,Q,R>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, float, double>::type,
        P<int, long, Q<bool, R<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_simple_nested_pack<Z<2,1>, Z<3,2>, A<P,Q>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, float, double>::type,
        P<int, long, Q<bool, Q<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_simple_nested_pack<Z<2,1,0>, Z<3,2,2>, A<P>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>::type,
        P<int, long, P<bool, P<P<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float, double>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_simple_nested_pack<Z<2,1,0>, Z<3,2,2>, A<P,Q,R>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>::type,
        P<int, long, Q<bool, R<R<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float, double>
    >::value);

    using NestedPack = P<int, long, Q<bool, R<R<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float, double>;
    using PackTraits = simple_nested_pack_traits<NestedPack>;

    static_assert(PackTraits::value == true);
    static_assert(simple_nested_pack_traits<int>::value == false);
//  static_assert(simple_nested_pack_traits<P<int, long, P<char>, P<bool>, float>::value == false);  // This won't compile because sibling inner packs are not supported (yet).

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        PackTraits::starting_positions,
        std::index_sequence<2,1,0>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        PackTraits::pack_lengths,
        std::index_sequence<3,2,2>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        PackTraits::templates,
        detail::generic::A<P,Q,R,R>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        PackTraits::types,
        P<int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>
    >::value);

    static_assert(PackTraits::depth == 3);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        PackTraits::types,
        P<int, long, bool, int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>
    >::value);

    // Now the flattening and restoration of a really nested pack:
    using ReallyNestedPack = P<int, long, Q<bool, R<R<int, P<bool, Q<double, int>>>, int>, char>, long, float, double>;
    using FlattenedPack = flatten_pack<ReallyNestedPack>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<FlattenedPack, P<int, long, bool, int, bool, double, int, int, char, long, float, double>>);
    using NestedPackTraits = simple_nested_pack_traits<ReallyNestedPack>;
    using RestoredPack = unflatten_pack<NestedPackTraits::starting_positions, NestedPackTraits::pack_lengths, NestedPackTraits::templates, FlattenedPack>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<RestoredPack, ReallyNestedPack>);
}
```

**Update:**

Ok, starting from scratch, I redefined `create_nested_pack` so that it can create any number of nested packs that are siblings to each other only, and these inner packs themselves have no further inner packs.  This was actually easier to write than the previous version (I kept all my meta-functions from my `detail` namespace from before even though most are not needed here at this early stage, because I'll probably need them later).  But my hunch is that this can be used recursively to get any depth of nestings:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
    template <typename T> struct is_pack : std::false_type { };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
    struct is_pack<P<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

    template <typename... Packs> struct merge;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q, typename... Us>
    struct merge<P<Ts...>, Q<Us...>> {
        using type = P<Ts..., Us...>;   
    };

    template <typename First, typename... Rest>
    struct merge<First, Rest...> : merge<First, typename merge<Rest...>::type> { };

    template <typename Pack> struct pack_size;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
    struct pack_size<P<Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> { };

    template <template <auto...> class Z, auto... Is>
    struct pack_size<Z<Is...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)> { };

    template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, T... Is>
    struct pack_size<Z<T, Is...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)> { };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto make_head (P<Ts...>&&, std::index_sequence<Is...>&&) -> P<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;

    template <std::size_t Size, typename Pack>
    struct head {  // Gives the first Size types in Pack.
        using type = decltype(make_head(std::declval<Pack>(), std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}));   
    };

    template <std::size_t Shift, template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto make_middle_section (P<Ts...>&&, std::index_sequence<Is...>&&) -> P<std::tuple_element_t<Is + Shift, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;

    template <std::size_t Skip, std::size_t Size, typename Pack>
    struct middle_section {  // Gives all the Size types in Pack after the first Skip types.
        using type = decltype(make_middle_section<Skip>(std::declval<Pack>(), std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}));   
    };

    template <std::size_t Skip, typename Pack>  // Gives all the types of Pack except for the first Skip types.
    struct exclude_head : middle_section<Skip, pack_size<Pack>::value - Skip, Pack> { };

    template <typename Pack> struct sum;

    template <template <auto...> class Z, auto... Is>
    struct sum<Z<Is...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, (0 + ... + Is)> { };

    template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class...> struct change_template;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q>
    struct change_template<P<Ts...>, Q> {
        using type = Q<Ts...>;  
    };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q, template <typename...> class R, template <typename...> class... Rest>
    struct change_template<P<Ts...>, Q, R, Rest...> {
        using type = R<Ts...>;  // For create_nested_pack_h, we want to switch to the second template if there is a second template.
    };

    template <typename Pack, typename T> struct append;
    template <typename Pack, auto Value> struct append_to_sequence;
    template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P> struct append_template;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename T>
    struct append<P<Ts...>, T> {
        using type = P<Ts..., T>;   
    };


    template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, auto... Is, auto Value>
    struct append_to_sequence<Z<T, Is...>, Value> {
        using type = Z<T, Is..., Value>;    
    };

    template <template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class... Ps, template <typename...> class P>
    struct append_template<A<Ps...>, P> {
        using type = A<Ps..., P>;
    };

    struct generic {
        template <std::size_t... Is> struct K;
        template <template <typename...> class...> struct L;

        template <std::size_t... Is>
        using Z = K<Is...>;

        template <template <typename...> class... Ps>
        using A = L<Ps...>;
    };
}

// Not sure if Length is needed, but it was needed in the previous code, so I'll keep it here for now.
template <std::size_t Length, typename Positions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename Types> struct create_nested_pack_h;

// The last sibling inner pack has been constructed.  The rest of the pack is just 'tail' from the previous.
template <std::size_t Length, template <std::size_t...> class Z, template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class... Ps, typename Types>
struct create_nested_pack_h<Length, Z<>, Z<>, A<P, Ps...>, Types> {
    using type = Types;
};

// An inner pack is reached and completed.
template <std::size_t Length, template <std::size_t...> class Z, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t J, std::size_t... Js, template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class... Ps, typename Types>
struct create_nested_pack_h<Length, Z<I, Is...>, Z<J, Js...>, A<P, Ps...>, Types> {
    using head_of_pack = typename detail::head<I, Types>::type;  // The wrapping template used is P.
    using templates_left = std::conditional_t<sizeof...(Ps) == 0, A<P>, A<Ps...>>;  // If sizeof...(Ps) == 0, then we use P as the wrapping template for all remaining inner packs.
    using inner_pack = typename detail::middle_section<I, J, Types>::type;
    static constexpr size_t new_length = Length - 1 - I;  // Check this later, when it is needed (if at all).
    using tail = typename detail::exclude_head<I + J, Types>::type;
    using type = typename detail::merge<head_of_pack, P<inner_pack>, typename create_nested_pack_h<new_length, Z<(Is - I - 1)...>, Z<Js...>, templates_left, tail>::type>::type;

};

template <typename Positions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename... Types> struct create_nested_pack;

template <typename Positions, typename PackLengths, template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class... Ps, typename... Ts>
struct create_nested_pack<Positions, PackLengths, A<P, Ps...>, Ts...> :
    create_nested_pack_h<sizeof...(Ts) - (detail::sum<PackLengths>::value - detail::pack_size<PackLengths>::value), Positions, PackLengths, A<P, Ps...>, P<Ts...>> { };

// Test
template <typename...> struct P;
template <typename...> struct Q;
template <typename...> struct R;
template <std::size_t...> struct Z;
template <template <typename...> class...> struct A;

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_nested_pack<Z<2,4,7>, Z<3,2,1>, A<P>, int, long, char, bool, short, float, double, std::size_t, int, char, float, short, bool, char, int, bool>::type,
        P<int, long, P<char, bool, short>, float, P<double, std::size_t>, int, char, P<float>, short, bool, char, int, bool>
    >::value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't simple :(

Anyway... I don't think it's a good idea separate list of start points, list of lengths and list of containers. It's difficult to read and, if you want mix sequential and nested case, it's difficult to manage.

I think you should express this information in a sequential/recursive way.

I propose to define your `Z` in this way

```
template <template <typename...> class C, std::size_t S, std::size_t L,  
          typename... Zs>
struct Z
 { };
```

where `C` is the container (`P`, `Q`, `R`, `std::tuple`, etc.), `S` is the starting point, `L` is the length and `Zs...` is a sequential list of the (optionals) nested `Z`s.

And I propose to define `create_nested_pack` (renamed `CNP`; sorry: I'm lazy) as follows

```
template <typename...>
struct CNP;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Zs, typename ... Ts>
struct CNP<C<Zs...>, Ts...> 
   : public CNPh<C<>, 0U, std::size_t(-1), std::tuple<Ts...>, Zs...>
 { };
```

where `C` is the external container, `Zs...` is a list of `Z`s and `Ts...` is the list of types to pack.

The recursive helper struct, `CNPh`, is defined as follows

```
template <typename C, std::size_t P, std::size_t L, typename T,
          typename ... Zs>
struct CNPh;
```

where `C` is the growing container, `P` is the position, `L` is the length, `T` is the `std::tuple` wrapping the available types and `Zs` is a list of `Z`s to insert in `C`.

`CNPh` is implemented through some partial specialization, as you can see in the following example (hoping it's clear; if isn't, ask and I'll try to explain)

**-- EDIT --**

Added a reverse type traits (NPT), as the OP requested

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename...> class, std::size_t, std::size_t, typename...>
struct Z
 { };

template <typename, std::size_t, std::size_t, typename, typename...>
struct CNPh;

template <template <typename...> class C0, typename ... Ts0,
          std::size_t I, std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts1,
          template <typename...> class C1, std::size_t ZI,
          std::size_t ZN, typename ... Zs1, typename ... Zs2>
struct CNPh<C0<Ts0...>, I, N, std::tuple<T, Ts1...>,
            Z<C1, ZI, ZN, Zs1...>, Zs2...>
   : public CNPh<C0<Ts0..., T>, I+1U, N, std::tuple<Ts1...>,
                 Z<C1, ZI, ZN, Zs1...>, Zs2...>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C0, typename ... Ts0,
          std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts1,
          template <typename...> class C1, std::size_t ZI, std::size_t ZN,
          typename ... Zs1, typename ... Zs2>
struct CNPh<C0<Ts0...>, N, N, std::tuple<T, Ts1...>,
            Z<C1, ZI, ZN, Zs1...>, Zs2...>
 {
   using restTypes = std::tuple<T, Ts1...>;
   using type      = C0<Ts0...>;
 }; 

template <template <typename...> class C0, typename ... Ts0,
          std::size_t I, std::size_t N, typename ... Zs>
struct CNPh<C0<Ts0...>, I, N, std::tuple<>, Zs...>
 {
   using restTypes = std::tuple<>;
   using type      = C0<Ts0...>;
 };

template <template <typename...> class C0, typename ... Ts0,
          std::size_t I, std::size_t N>
struct CNPh<C0<Ts0...>, I, N, std::tuple<>>
   : public CNPh<C0<Ts0...>, I, N, std::tuple<>, Z<C0, std::size_t(-1), 0U>>
 { };


template <template <typename...> class C0, typename ... Ts0,
          std::size_t I, std::size_t N, typename T, typename ... Ts1,
          template <typename...> class C1, std::size_t ZN,
          typename ... Zs1, typename ... Zs2>
struct CNPh<C0<Ts0...>, I, N, std::tuple<T, Ts1...>,
            Z<C1, I, ZN, Zs1...>, Zs2...>
 {
   using subType   = CNPh<C1<>, 0U, ZN, std::tuple<T, Ts1...>, Zs1...>;
   using nextType  = CNPh<C0<Ts0..., typename subType::type>, I+1U, N,
                          typename subType::restTypes, Zs2...>;
   using restTypes = typename nextType::restTypes;
   using type      = typename nextType::type;
 };

template <template <typename...> class C0, typename ... Ts0, std::size_t I,
          std::size_t N, typename ... Ts1>
struct CNPh<C0<Ts0...>, I, N, std::tuple<Ts1...>>
   : public CNPh<C0<Ts0...>, I, N, std::tuple<Ts1...>,
                 Z<C0, std::size_t(-1), 0U>>
 { };

template <typename...>
struct CNP;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Zs, typename ... Ts>
struct CNP<C<Zs...>, Ts...> 
   : public CNPh<C<>, 0U, std::size_t(-1), std::tuple<Ts...>, Zs...>
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
using CNP_t = typename CNP<Ts...>::type;

template <typename, std::size_t, typename ...>
struct NPTh2;

template <typename C, std::size_t Pos, typename ... Ts>
using NPTh2_t = typename NPTh2<C, Pos, Ts...>::type;

template <typename C, std::size_t Pos, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct NPTh2<C, Pos, T0, Ts...> : public NPTh2<C, Pos+1U, Ts...>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C0, std::size_t S, std::size_t L,
          typename ... Zs, std::size_t Pos, template <typename...> class C1,
          typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
struct NPTh2<Z<C0, S, L, Zs...>, Pos, C1<Ts1...>, Ts2...>
   : public NPTh2<Z<C0, S, L, Zs...,
                  NPTh2_t<Z<C1, Pos, sizeof...(Ts1)>, 0U, Ts1...>>,
                  Pos+1U, Ts2...>
 { };

template <typename C, std::size_t Pos>
struct NPTh2<C, Pos>
 { using type = C; };

template <typename, std::size_t, typename ...>
struct NPTh1;

template <typename C, std::size_t Pos, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct NPTh1<C, Pos, T0, Ts...> : public NPTh1 <C, Pos+1U, Ts...>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C0, typename ... Zs,
          std::size_t Pos, template <typename...> class C1,
          typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
struct NPTh1<C0<Zs...>, Pos, C1<Ts1...>, Ts2...>
   : public NPTh1<C0<Zs..., NPTh2_t<Z<C1, Pos, sizeof...(Ts1)>, 0U, Ts1...>>,
                  Pos+1U, Ts2...>
 { };

template <typename C, std::size_t Pos>
struct NPTh1<C, Pos>
 { using type = C; };

template <typename>
struct NPT;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct NPT<C<Ts...>> : NPTh1<C<>, 0U, Ts...>
 { };

template <typename T>
using NPT_t = typename NPT<T>::type;

template <typename...> struct P { };
template <typename...> struct Q { };
template <typename...> struct R { };

int main ()
 {
   // former create_nested_pack<Z<2>, Z<3>, A<P>, int, long, bool, int,
   //                           bool, char, int>
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<P, 2U, 3U>>, int, long, bool, int, bool, char, int>,
      P<int, long, P<bool, int, bool>, char, int>>{});

   // former create_nested_pack<Z<2>, Z<3>, A<P,Q>, int, long, bool, int,
   //                           bool, char, int>
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U>>, int, long, bool, int, bool, char, int>,
      P<int, long, Q<bool, int, bool>, char, int>>{});

   // former create_nested_pack<Z<2,1>, Z<3,2>, A<P>, int, long, bool, int,
   //                           bool, int, char, float, double>
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<P, 2U, 3U, Z<P, 1U, 2U>>>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int,
            char, float, double>, 
      P<int, long, P<bool, P<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>>{});

   // former create_nested_pack<Z<2,1>, Z<3,2>, A<P,Q,R>, int, long, bool,
   //                           int, bool, int, char, float, double>
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<R, 1U, 2U>>>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int,
            char, float, double>, 
      P<int, long, Q<bool, R<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>>{});

   // former create_nested_pack<Z<2,1>, Z<3,2>, A<P,Q>, int, long, bool, int,
   //                           bool, int, char, float, double>
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<Q, 1U, 2U>>>, int, long, bool, int, bool, int,
            char, float, double>, 
      P<int, long, Q<bool, Q<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>>{});

   // former create_nested_pack<Z<2,1,0>, Z<3,2,2>, A<P>, int, long, bool,
   //                           int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<P, 2U, 3U, Z<P, 1U, 2U, Z<P, 0U, 2U>>>>, int, long, bool,
            int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>, 
      P<int, long, P<bool, P<P<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float, double>
      >{});

   // former create_nested_pack<Z<2,1,0>, Z<3,2,2>, A<P,Q,R>, int, long,
   //                           bool, int, bool, int, char, long, float,
   //                           double>
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<R, 1U, 2U, Z<R, 0U, 2U>>>>, int, long, bool,
            int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>, 
      P<int, long, Q<bool, R<R<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float, double>
      >{});

   // sequential case
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U>, Z<R, 4U, 2U>, Z<R, 5U, 2U>>, int, long, bool,
            int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>, 
      P<int, long, Q<bool, int, bool>, int, R<char, long>, R<float, double>>
      >{});

   // sequential/nested case
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U>, Z<R, 4U, 2U, Z<P, 1U, 2U>>>, int, long, bool,
            int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>, 
      P<int, long, Q<bool, int, bool>, int, R<char, P<long, float>>, double>
      >{});

   // nested/sequential case
   static_assert(std::is_same<
      CNP_t<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<R, 1U, 2U>, Z<P, 2U, 2U>>>, int, long, bool,
            int, bool, int, char, long, float, double>, 
      P<int, long, Q<bool, R<int, bool>, P<int, char>>, long, float, double>
      >{});

   // reverse tests
   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<P, 2U, 3U>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, P<bool, int, bool>, char, int>>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, Q<bool, int, bool>, char, int>>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<P, 2U, 3U, Z<P, 1U, 2U>>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, P<bool, P<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>>
      >{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<R, 1U, 2U>>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, Q<bool, R<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>>
      >{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<Q, 1U, 2U>>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, Q<bool, Q<int, bool>, int>, char, float, double>>
      >{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<P, 2U, 3U, Z<P, 1U, 2U, Z<P, 0U, 2U>>>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, P<bool, P<P<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float,
            double>>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<R, 1U, 2U, Z<R, 0U, 2U>>>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, Q<bool, R<R<int, bool>, int>, char>, long, float,
            double>>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U>, Z<R, 4U, 2U>, Z<R, 5U, 2U>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, Q<bool, int, bool>, int, R<char, long>,
            R<float, double>>>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U>, Z<R, 4U, 2U, Z<P, 1U, 2U>>>,
      NPT_t<P<int, long, Q<bool, int, bool>, int, R<char, P<long, float>>,
            double>>>{});

   static_assert(std::is_same<P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<R, 1U, 2U>, Z<P, 2U, 2U>>>, 
      NPT_t<P<int, long, Q<bool, R<int, bool>, P<int, char>>, long, float,
            double>>>{});
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this design (and I wasn't expecting a full solution!).  I will look into it later, but my updated code above suggests that I can still keep the input parameters linear and get it to work, though it may be harder to read like you suggested, and will keep working on that.  Then I'll compare to your solution (which seems a lot shorter!) to learn from it.

Comment: @ max66   By the way, one of the reasons why I want to keep the input templates linear is that afterwards I want to write a `nested_pack_traits` class that will obtain all the inner pack lengths, starting positions, and containers (which I can only see being extracted in linear form), and thus any nested pack can be flattened and then restored using those extracted traits.  I've updated my `create_simple_nested_pack.cpp` in my question where I illustrate that usage (at the end of main()).

Comment: @prestokeys - not sure to understand but... can be useful if I wrote a `NPT` traits that return my version of `Z`s? I mean: something that given (by example) `P<int, long, Q<bool, R<int, bool>, P<int, char>>, long, float, double>` return the `type` `P<Z<Q, 2U, 3U, Z<R, 1U, 2U>, Z<P, 2U, 2U>>>`.

Comment: @ max66  Yeah, I thought of that after I wrote my comment, thus removing any need for linearity.  Your `NPT` traits class might be just as hard to write as your `CNP` class though.

Comment: @prestokeys - answer modified and `NPT` added; this time I've used two helper function but seems, to me, reasonably simple (and I suppose can be simplified a little).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using my original method.  It is used like this:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<
    create_nested_pack<database<W<S<>, Z<1,2,4,7>, Z<2,5,2,4>, A<P,Q,R>>,
                                W<S<0>, Z<0>, Z<1>, A<R>>,
                                W<S<1>, Z<0,2>, Z<1,4>, A<R,P>>,
                                W<S<1,1>, Z<1,2>, Z<1,2>, A<P, std::tuple>>,
                                W<S<1,1,1>, Z<0,1>, Z<3,2>, A<Q>>,
                                W<S<1,1,1,0>, Z<0,2>, Z<1,3>, A<R,P>>,
                                W<S<3>, Z<1>, Z<2>, A<std::tuple>>>,
        P<int, long, int, char, bool, short, long, std::size_t, int, int, bool, bool, char, float, long, int, bool, float, double, std::size_t, int, char, float, short, bool, char, int, bool>>::type,
    P<int, P<R<long>, int>, Q<R<char>, bool, P<short, P<long>, std::tuple<Q<R<std::size_t>, int, P<int, bool, bool>>, Q<char, float>>, long>, int, bool>, float, R<double, std::size_t>, int, char, R<float, std::tuple<short, bool>, char, int>, bool>
>::value);
```

The `S<Is...>` are signatures representing which child the positions, lengths, and containers are the inner packs of.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
    template <typename T> struct is_pack : std::false_type { };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
    struct is_pack<P<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

    template <typename... Packs> struct merge;

    template <typename Pack>
    struct merge<Pack> { using type = Pack; };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q, typename... Us>
    struct merge<P<Ts...>, Q<Us...>> {
        using type = P<Ts..., Us...>;   
    };

    template <template <auto...> class Z, auto... Is, auto... Js>
    struct merge<Z<Is...>, Z<Js...>> {
        using type = Z<Is..., Js...>;   
    };

    template <typename First, typename... Rest>
    struct merge<First, Rest...> : merge<First, typename merge<Rest...>::type> { };

    template <typename Pack> struct merge_contents;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
    struct merge_contents<P<Ts...>> : merge<Ts...> { };

    template <typename Pack> struct pack_size;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
    struct pack_size<P<Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> { };

    template <template <auto...> class Z, auto... Is>
    struct pack_size<Z<Is...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)> { };

    template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, T... Is>
    struct pack_size<Z<T, Is...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)> { };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto make_head (P<Ts...>&&, std::index_sequence<Is...>&&) -> P<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;

    template <std::size_t Size, typename Pack, typename = void>
    struct head {  // Gives the first Size types in Pack.
        using type = decltype(make_head(std::declval<Pack>(), std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}));   
    };

    template <std::size_t Shift, template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto make_middle_section (P<Ts...>&&, std::index_sequence<Is...>&&) -> P<std::tuple_element_t<Is + Shift, std::tuple<Ts...>>...>;

    template <std::size_t Skip, std::size_t Size, typename Pack>
    struct middle_section {  // Gives all the Size types in Pack after the first Skip types.
        using type = decltype(make_middle_section<Skip>(std::declval<Pack>(), std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}));   
    };

    template <std::size_t Skip, typename Pack>  // Gives all the types of Pack except for the first Skip types.
    struct exclude_head : middle_section<Skip, pack_size<Pack>::value - Skip, Pack> { };

    template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class...> struct change_template;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q>
    struct change_template<P<Ts...>, Q> {
        using type = Q<Ts...>;  
    };

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q, template <typename...> class R, template <typename...> class... Rest>
    struct change_template<P<Ts...>, Q, R, Rest...> {
        using type = R<Ts...>;  // For create_nested_pack_h, we want to switch to the second template if there is a second template.
    };

    template <typename Pack> struct get_pack_lengths;

    template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
    struct get_pack_lengths<P<Ts...>> {
        using type = P<typename Ts::pack_lengths...>;
    };

    template <typename Sequence> struct sum;

    template <template <auto...> class Z, auto I, auto... Is>
    struct sum<Z<I, Is...>> : std::integral_constant<decltype(I), (I + ... + Is)> {};
}

// S for signature.  A series of whole numbers that describes the tree position of the inner pack, with 0 representing the leftmost child of the parent pack.
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct S {
    template <std::size_t I>
    using append = S<Is..., I>;
};

template <typename S, typename Positions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates>
struct W {
    using signature = S;
    using positions = Positions;
    using pack_lengths = PackLengths;
    using templates = Templates;
};

template <typename...> struct database;

template <typename Signature, typename Positions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename... Ws>
struct database<W<Signature, Positions, PackLengths, Templates>, Ws...> {
    template <typename S>
    using look_up = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<S, Signature>, 
        W<Signature, Positions, PackLengths, Templates>,
        typename database<Ws...>::template look_up<S>
    >;
};

template <>
struct database<> {
    struct nonesuch;

    template <typename S>
    using look_up = nonesuch;   
};

template <std::size_t ChildNumber, std::size_t Length, typename Signature, typename Database, typename Positions, typename PackLengths, typename Templates, typename Types> struct create_nested_pack_h;

// The last sibling inner pack has been constructed.  The rest of the pack is just 'tail' from the previous.
template <std::size_t ChildNumber, std::size_t Length, typename Signature, typename Database, template <std::size_t...> class Z, template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class... Ps, typename Types>
struct create_nested_pack_h<ChildNumber, Length, Signature, Database, Z<>, Z<>, A<P, Ps...>, Types> {
    using type = typename detail::head<Length, Types>::type;
    static constexpr std::size_t num_types = Length;  // Used to have '(Length < detail::pack_size<Types>::value) ? Length : detail::pack_size<Types>::value;' when detail::pack_size<Pack>::value was used in place of final_pack_size in create_nested_pack below.
};

template <std::size_t Length, typename Signature, typename Database, typename w, typename Types>
struct get_inner_pack : create_nested_pack_h<0, Length, Signature, Database, typename w::positions, typename w::pack_lengths, typename w::templates, Types> { };

template <std::size_t Length, typename Signature, typename Database, typename Types>
struct get_inner_pack<Length, Signature, Database, database<>::nonesuch, Types> {
    using type = typename detail::head<Length, Types>::type;
    static constexpr std::size_t num_types = Length;
};

// An inner pack is reached and completed.
template <std::size_t ChildNumber, std::size_t Length, typename Signature, typename Database, template <std::size_t...> class Z, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t J, std::size_t... Js, template <template <typename...> class...> class A, template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class... Ps, typename Types>
struct create_nested_pack_h<ChildNumber, Length, Signature, Database, Z<I, Is...>, Z<J, Js...>, A<P, Ps...>, Types> {
    using head_of_pack = typename detail::head<I, Types>::type;
    using templates_left = std::conditional_t<sizeof...(Ps) == 0, A<P>, A<Ps...>>;  // If sizeof...(Ps) == 0, then we use P as the wrapping template for all remaining inner packs.
    using sig = typename Signature::template append<ChildNumber>;
    using w = typename Database::template look_up<sig>;  // Check if Database lists this inner pack as having its own inner packs.  If not, then w is database<>::nonesuch.
    using after_head = typename detail::change_template<typename detail::exclude_head<I, Types>::type, P>::type;
    using inner = get_inner_pack<J, sig, Database, w, after_head>;  // J is the length of the inner pack (if any).
    using inner_pack = typename inner::type;
    using tail = typename detail::change_template<typename detail::exclude_head<I + inner::num_types, Types>::type, P, Ps...>::type;
    using continuation = create_nested_pack_h<ChildNumber + 1, Length - I - 1, Signature, Database, Z<(Is - I - 1)...>, Z<Js...>, templates_left, tail>;  // Seek the next sibling inner pack (if any).
                // Length - I - 1 is used because Length has been reduced by the length of head_of_pack (with is I) and the inner_pack takes up length of 1 in this pack.
    using type = typename detail::merge<head_of_pack, P<inner_pack>, typename continuation::type>::type;
    static constexpr std::size_t num_types = I + inner::num_types + continuation::num_types;    
};

template <typename Database, typename Pack>
struct create_nested_pack {
    using w = typename Database::template look_up<S<>>;
    using all_pack_lengths = typename detail::merge_contents<typename detail::get_pack_lengths<Database>::type>::type;
    static constexpr std::size_t final_pack_size = detail::pack_size<Pack>::value - detail::sum<all_pack_lengths>::value + detail::pack_size<all_pack_lengths>::value;  // Mathematically, the length of the final pack is the length of Pack - accumulative lengths of all the inner packs + the number of inner packs.
    using type = typename create_nested_pack_h<0, final_pack_size, S<>, Database, typename w::positions, typename w::pack_lengths, typename w::templates, Pack>::type; 
};

// Test
template <typename...> struct P;
template <typename...> struct Q;
template <typename...> struct R;
template <std::size_t...> struct Z;
template <template <typename...> class...> struct A;

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_nested_pack<database<W<S<>, Z<2,4,7>, Z<3,2,1>, A<P,Q>>>,
            P<int, long, char, bool, short, float, double, std::size_t, int, char, float, short, bool, char, int, bool>>::type,
        P<int, long, P<char, bool, short>, float, Q<double, std::size_t>, int, char, Q<float>, short, bool, char, int, bool>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_nested_pack<database<W<S<>, Z<2,4,7>, Z<3,2,4>, A<P,Q>>, W<S<2>, Z<1>, Z<2>, A<R>>>,
            P<int, long, char, bool, short, float, double, std::size_t, int, char, float, short, bool, char, int, bool>>::type,
        P<int, long, P<char, bool, short>, float, Q<double, std::size_t>, int, char, Q<float, R<short, bool>, char, int>, bool>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_nested_pack<database<W<S<>, Z<2,4,7>, Z<5,2,4>, A<P,Q,R>>, W<S<0>, Z<0,2>, Z<1,4>, A<P,Q>>, W<S<2>, Z<1>, Z<2>, A<Q>>>,
            P<int, long, char, bool, short, long, std::size_t, char, int, bool, float, double, std::size_t, int, char, float, short, bool, char, int, bool>>::type,
            P<int, long, P<P<char>, bool, Q<short, long, std::size_t, char>, int, bool>, float, Q<double, std::size_t>, int, char, R<float, Q<short, bool>, char, int>, bool>
    >::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        create_nested_pack<database<W<S<>, Z<1,2,4,7>, Z<2,5,2,4>, A<P,Q,R>>,
                                    W<S<0>, Z<0>, Z<1>, A<R>>,
                                    W<S<1>, Z<0,2>, Z<1,4>, A<R,P>>,
                                    W<S<1,1>, Z<1,2>, Z<1,2>, A<P, std::tuple>>,
                                    W<S<1,1,1>, Z<0,1>, Z<3,2>, A<Q>>,
                                    W<S<1,1,1,0>, Z<0,2>, Z<1,3>, A<R,P>>,
                                    W<S<3>, Z<1>, Z<2>, A<std::tuple>>>,
            P<int, long, int, char, bool, short, long, std::size_t, int, int, bool, bool, char, float, long, int, bool, float, double, std::size_t, int, char, float, short, bool, char, int, bool>>::type,
        P<int, P<R<long>, int>, Q<R<char>, bool, P<short, P<long>, std::tuple<Q<R<std::size_t>, int, P<int, bool, bool>>, Q<char, float>>, long>, int, bool>, float, R<double, std::size_t>, int, char, R<float, std::tuple<short, bool>, char, int>, bool>
    >::value);
}
```

I will try to solve this using max66's more elegant design now (without reading his solution).